# Send parameters into main function of another script

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to send function and parameters into the main function of other script .For example in `a.py` I have:

```
#a.py

if __name__=='__main__':
    p=multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    results=p.map(task,args)
```

And In script `b.py` I have:

```
def task(x):
    return x*x
args=range(10)
```

How can I send `task` and `args` of `b.py` into the main function of `a.py` **without modifying `a.py`**? That is,I want to send function and parameters into a module to do parallel programming without modifying this module.

Answer (score 0):

In `a.py`, before inserting any code, add the line:

```
import b
```

Or if you only want to import the function `task` and `args` use:

```
from b import task
from b import args
```

Make sure `a.py` and `b.py` are in the same directory.